# Handling paths in portable JAR

Tags: java

I have written a java program which different classes where during the process it generates lots of files (say txt files) and then reads the files and operates on them. I have made the project as a JAR file where I can run it from command with no problem as JAR is in the same directory. 
However, I want to run this JAR file on a remote server where the PATHs are not the same, so then it generates error, because in my project for instance it should read a file from /Programs/Folder/here whereas in the server this cannot happen as there is no /Programs/Folder... directory. Do I have to change all the paths in my program according to the new location I wanna put my jar or there is another way around it? 
I would appreciate your help.
Best wishes

Comment: Why not passing the path to read by arguments?

Comment: Consider also using relative paths.

Comment: Are you using relative or absolute paths?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what i prefer is i use relative path and then read relative path using classloader.try it.

Comment: thanks for your answer. But would you please give an example. I am afraid I couldnt understand, even if use file.getAbsolutePath(). for instance my code files are in  /Programs/Folder1/folder2/..java where the files being produced and written and read are in /Programs/Folder1/Folder3/..txt and I need to move the entire project to another server where the folder names are very different

Answer (score 1):

I would think the best way is to pass the directory name where the files in as an argumrnt to the java command line.

Read it from the parameter args in main

Answer (score 1):

This simplest and best solution is to change all of your paths in files inside of your project to be relative paths. You can also simply pass the directory you would like the files stored in to `String args[]` as parameters